# How to create a separation of interests between the 'stories' and '.storybook' folders?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, storybook, react-typescript

## Context

By default, Storybook.js has integrated with my existing Create-React-App project by creating two new folders:

- `.storybook`
- src/`stories`

I don't like this because it feels like a mixing of interests. The point of Storybook is to keep the business logic of the app totally seperate.

## Problem

I've tried moving the `stories` directory inside of the `.storybook` one. Now, though, there's an infinite loading spinner (even though there are no errors listed in the terminal or browser console).

*Sometimes*, if I wait long enough, I'll get this error message in the console:

```bash
Loading chunk vendors-node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_assertThisInitialized_js-node_modules_babel_ru-6be1ea failed.

(timeout: http://localhost:6006/vendors-node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_assertThisInitialized_js-node_modules_babel_ru-6be1ea.iframe.bundle.js)
```

## Current Situation

Here's a summary of my current directory organization:

- `.storybook`

  - `/stories`
  - `/assets`
  - `main.ts`

Below are the directory-related parts of my config inside `main.ts`.

```bash
import type { StorybookConfig } from "@storybook/react-webpack5";


const config: StorybookConfig = {
  stories: ["./stories/**/*.mdx", "./stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"],
  staticDirs: ["./assets"],
};
```

## Attempted Solutions

### Create a shared parent directory

I tried to create a parent folder, thinking maybe I could store `.storybook` and `stories` inside a folder where they'd be next to each other, rather than `stories` nested inside of `.storybook`, but then I had trouble figuring out how to have `.storybook` be identified when trying to run the `npm run storybook` script.

I've read various articles about WebPack (I'm using `v5`), but I haven't been able to make heads or tails of it.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I also considered this for a while. I had originally even setup storybook as a separate npm/yarn workspace.

However, now that we are deeper into storybook and that we have embraced their interaction testing (visual component testing), I appreciate having the stories next to the component they document/test.

This comes also from a move that I am driving in my team to refactor our code to follow a more domain based structure. So far, I have seen a lot of react projects being structured based on technical grouping (which I personally find to be an anti-pattern - it goes against encapsulation and code-cohesion). I like having everything that has to do with the component, within that components folder (aside from shared dependencies of course).

Funnily enough, in our backend projects we do have domain based structuring with [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) tests (and soon [Spring Modulith](https://spring.io/projects/spring-modulith), there is an interesting talk about it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjSjBZ7mo1g)). We are not as far as to introducing ArchUnit-style tests for the frontend yet, but that would be the goal.

We have setup this folder structure:

```
- component
  Component.tsx
  __storybook__
    Component.stories.tsx
    Component.stories-docs.tsx
    // depending on the size of the component, we may have other files here, like fixtures and page-objects (yes, I know they are controversial)
```